# DRF: Functional view not returning Response as expected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In the Django Rest Framework, I am looking to have my view return a personalised message using the following line:

`return Response({"Message":f"Post {pk} successfully {prefix}liked by {destination}"})`

What I expect it to return:

`{'Message': 'Post 130 successfully liked by 8'}`

What is actually returned:

`<Response [200]>`

Why is this happening? How can I return the expected message?

Here is the full view if it helps:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def like_view(request, pk, destination):
    #destination is the user_id
    post = Posts.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if post.is_expired == True:
        print("expired")
        return Response({"message":"post expired"})

    if check_self_action(destination,post):
        return Response({"message":"cannot like own post"})

    liked = check_like(destination, post)

    prefix = ""

    if liked:
        post.likes.remove(destination)
        prefix = "un"
    else:
        post.likes.add(destination) 

    return Response({"Message":f"Post {pk} successfully {prefix}liked by {destination}"})
```

Comment: Are you using `requests` and just printing the response? Use `response.json()` to access the JSON data in the response

Comment: This is only what it *prints*. The response contains the proper message.

Comment: where do you print this message (Ideally it should be viewed in the browser page with corresponding route)?

Comment: @MaranSowthri: If you make an AJAX request in the browser, the response will be a response with A JavaScript object in the response. The point is that if you use the `requests` library and you print a *response* object, it will simply print `<Response [statuscode]>` and nothing else, but that does not mean that that is the response, it is only what the `__str__` of a response shows.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you were correct that I forgot to put .json() on the end of the response from ```requests```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only what it *prints* when you print the message (call `str(…)` on it). The response contains the proper message.

If you for example work with the [**`requests`** package](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), then you can obtain the JSON content with the [**`.json()`** method [requests-doc]](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

```
response = requests.post('www.some-domain.com/some/path/with/values')
print(response.json())
```

You can also access the response as binary content with the [**`.content`** attribute [requests-doc]](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

```
response = requests.post('www.some-domain.com/some/path/with/values')
print(response.content)
```

which will return a `bytes` object with the response, here thus a JSON blob.